# mysql aggregate multiple columns by hour

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate

Had a quick look through and couldn't find my question again. So I'm hoping someone here can help.
I have a large table with a similar structure to the below.

`DateTime | InboundUserID | OutboundUserID | CustomerUserID | Cost | Mins | Account Number`

I'm trying to group the above data into hourly chunks and store the result in another table with a similar structure to below.

`Date | HourFrom | HourTo | SumMins | SumCost | OutboundUserID | CustomerUserID | Account Number`

I've written the following code / query in order to do this but it's not quite right. Basically the group by means not all the data gets summarised. For instance when looking at the newly created table I have all the OutboundUserID data, but none of the CustomerUserID data.

```
    for(int i=0;i <=23;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1 ; j <=31 ; j++)
        {
            String Time = String.format("%02d", i);

            query = "INSERT DELAYED INTO correlated_calls_hourly " +
                    " SELECT DateOnly,HourFrom,HourTo,DURATION,CALLCOUNT,`Price Group ID`,INBOUNDCOST,INBOUNDREVENUE,`InboundCustomerID`,OUTBOUNDCOST,OUTBOUNDREVENUE,`Outbound Customer ID`,`Customer ID`,`Account Number`,`Service` FROM" +
                    " ("+
                        " SELECT "+
                        /* snip sum(),case and date/time part of query */
                        " GROUP BY  DateOnly,`InboundCustomerID`,`OutboundCustomerID`,`CustomerID`,`AccountNumber`,`PriceGroupID`,`Service`" +
                    " )a ";
        }
    }
```

I've already taken the step of creating three different tables to summarise the data separately by OutboundUserID/ InboundUserID / CustomerUserID. But it would be a lot more elegant if I could just get this one summarised table working correctly.

If anyone could help me think of a way to get the desired result via a single sql query I'd be greatly appreciative.

Many thanks in advance

Alan

Comment: Have you considered using Views? Creating a single table seems a little bit too much if you just want to connect data together to have a kind of "report" table.

Comment: I had thought about this. Unfortunately the big table is is current 12 million rows in length, and grows by about 500,000 rows per day. I believe this is out of the scope for a simple view?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
INSERT INTO correlated_calls_hourly (Date, HourFrom, HourTo, SumMins, SumCost, OutboundUserID, CustomerUserID, AccountNumber)
SELECT 
  CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112),
  hour(DateTime),
  hour(DateTime) + 1, 
  SUM(Mins),
  SUM(Cost),
  OutboundUserID,
  CustomerUserID,
  AccountNumber
GROUP BY
  CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112),
  hour(DateTime)
  OutboundUserID,
  CustomerUserID,
  AccountNumber
```

The convert function is convert the datetime to just a date. You'd probably need to tweak it a little to suit your RDBMS but I can't see any reason why that wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue was with the grouping by more than one key values (InboundUserID | OutboundUserID | CustomerUserID) which wasn't working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After a little inspiration I realised the solution was obvious. Concat the columns together and do a group by on the concatenated column.

CONCAT(InboundUserID,'*',OutboundUserID,'*',CustomerUserID) as uniqueKey
GROUP BY uniqueKey.